Can I pass two variables, x and y, to a function defined by one variable v? I need to make a surface plot
I need to make a surface plot of a mountains function. The mountains function has one argument, but I need to give it X and Y so I can make the 3d surface plot.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize

x=np.linspace(-1,2,100)
y=np.linspace(-1,2,100)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
def mountains(v):
  func = (1-v[0])**2+100*(v[1]-v[0]*v[0])**2+0.3*(0.2-2*v[1])**2+100*(v[0]-v[1]*v[1])**2-0.5*(v[0]**2+5*v[1]**2)
  return func
Z=mountains(np.array([X.flatten(), Y.flatten()]).T).reshape(X.shape)


Before trying to actually make the plot, I tried making a variable Z and making it equal to the function with X and Y passed to it. I got the error "mountains() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given."
UPDATE: I think I got it right now. I changed
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)

to
v=np.meshgrid(x,y)

then did
Z=mountains(v)


v[1]-v[0]: v is a sequence like a tuple or list. That's one object holding multiple values inside it.
